# PHP Dynamic <FORM> name = col'.$i.'

Tags: php, post, dynamic

hope someone can help me with my problem.

Im generating a Form with a dynamic amount of Dropdown/

```
 while($length<count($spalten)) { 
    echo '<TD>
        <SELECT ID="col['.$length.']" name="col['.$length.']">'; 
           $selected = 0;
            echo $length;
              foreach( $spalten AS $value){
                  if($selected != $length){
                    echo '<OPTION value='.$value.'>'.$value.'</OPTION>';
                  }
                  else{
                      echo '<OPTION SELECTED value='.$value.'>'.$value.'</OPTION>';
                  }
                  $selected++;
               }
            echo '  </SELECT></TD>';
        $length++;
} ...
```

And than i try to get the values for them:

```
for( $i = 0; $i < $cols; $i++){          
        $insert = $insert.', $col'.$i.'='.$r[$i].' ' ;
    }
```

but $col'.$$i.' does not work of course, but i dont know how to handle that? how can i get the value of "$col0" and get it by $col$i???

hope someone knows

Thx so far

// EDIT

yeah sorry

$insert =  is sopposed to be a MySQL Insert Query

```
$q_fillreport = new DB_QS;
    $q_fillreport->query("INSERT INTO $typname 
                        SET reportid = $Id
                            $insert;");         
    }
```

and $col1 -> $colX are $_POST values from the

```
<SELECT ID="col['.$length.']" name="col['.$length.']">';
```

Comment: your question is not very clear